# AsyncTask android exception (Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once) although I create a new instance of AsyncTask like this

```
new ClientEngine(ip, port).execute(WindowsEventsEnum.MouseLeftButtonClick);
```

Here is my code

```
    public class ClientEngine extends AsyncTask<WindowsEventsEnum, Void, Void>{
    final String ip;
    final int port;
DatagramSocket socket;
    InetAddress remoteAdress;
    DatagramPacket sendingPacket;
    final String VOLUMEUP = "01";
    final String VOLUMEDOWN = "02";
    final String LMBCLICK = "11";
    final String RMBCLICK = "12";
    final String MMBUP = "21";
    final String MMBDOWN = "22";
    final String ENDCONNECTION = "ec";


    public ClientEngine(String ip, int port) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        remoteAdress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    }

    public void OpenConnection() throws IOException {


    }

    public void CloseConnection() throws IOException {

socket.close();
    }

    public void MouseLeftButtonClick() throws IOException {
byte[] sendDatagram = LMBCLICK.getBytes();
        sendingPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendDatagram, sendDatagram.length, remoteAdress, port);
        socket.send(sendingPacket);
    }

    public void MouseRightButtonClick() throws IOException {
        byte[] sendDatagram = RMBCLICK.getBytes();
        sendingPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendDatagram, sendDatagram.length, remoteAdress, port);
        socket.send(sendingPacket);
    }

    public void SystemVolumeUp() throws IOException {

    }

    public void SystemVolumeDown() throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(WindowsEventsEnum... params) {
        switch (params[0]) {
            case MouseLeftButtonClick:
                try {
                    MouseLeftButtonClick();
                    CloseConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case MouseRightButtonClick:
                try {
                    MouseRightButtonClick();
                    CloseConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
       return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to execute the same task twice, which is not allowed by AsyncTask. If you are still stuck, post the code where you are actually starting the tasks.

Comment: Its not the same. I create a new instance of class

Comment: Again, the error states otherwise, so we would need to see the code where you are starting your two tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry if you have already fixed the issue.
But generally, whenever you get an exception like this,

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)**

**Check whether you are following all the below mentioned rules:**

1. AsyncTask can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

   Just like the case where it is illegal to start a thread more than once.

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
> thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

So creating a new instance like `new asyncTask().execute();` is the only option

2. `onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), onProgressUpdate(),onPostExecute()` shouldn't be called manually.
3. The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
4. The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
5. execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.

Make sure you have followed all the 5 rules in your code.

Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html